# Can't find msbuild tools 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

I just downloaded xamarin studio and it says I need msbuild tools 2013. I installed it but now it need msbuild tool 2015 and I can't find it 
[on the official page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

Comment: Xamarin Studio? Why would someone not use VIsual Studio 2017 for that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, MSDN accounts have a ["previously downloaded" section](https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads). I don't remember downloading it before, but it was there regardless, so give it a shot.

If you don't find it, let me know and I can add a download link to the copy I got.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it.
You have to install Visual Studio Build Tools 2015:
http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

and install .NET SDK (So I did anyway).

This includes the MSBuild2015. I have been able to finally install Xamarin.

It sounds like Microsoft have been moving 'things' last days and those links were not active. Now they are !